# Spelling correction with Textblob for whole text file

Tags: python, codec, textblob

I've been trying to use the correct function of Textblob on an entire file and have the following code.

```
import codecs
import os

f = codecs.open("Source", "r", encoding="utf-8")
lines = f.readlines()

from textblob import TextBlob

tweet1 = TextBlob(lines[0])
tweet2 = TextBlob(lines[-1])


print(tweet1.correct())
print(tweet2.correct())
```

But i can't figure out how to make it correct each line of the file ?

Thank you for your help, 
Hal

Answer (score 3):

```
for line in lines:
    # TextBlob is providing correct method
    print(TextBlob(line).correct())
```

If you're not familiar with loops you need to go back to basics for a while.